# why there are some hot-module-replacement code in product?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-component

[image]

I am programing for a vue.js project.I use **webpack** to compile my source code to product.After the compilation completed,I found that there are some code for **hot-module-replacement**,is it necessary in product?

Answer (score 3):

The hot module code is guarded by:

```
if (false) {
  ...
}
```

It will never be reached. These unreachable statements are removed entirely when you uglify the code. You can use the webpack plugin `UglifyJsPlugin`:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
]
```

You can also enable production mode from the CLI with the `-p` flag:

```
webpack -p
```

For more details see [Building for Production](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production-build/).